# Is it possible to create date-specific triggers in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Experts.
I want to create date-specific trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics.
But I don't know if I can make that.
The trigger requirements I would like to make are as follows.

Execution Date(Do not Execute on January,April,July and October.)
Feb 4/Mar 4/May 6/Jun 3/Aug 5/Sep 2/Nov 4/Dec 2

Execution Time
・10 am on all execution dates

Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this but, in schedule trigger excluding certain months is not supported as of now. You can of course try having one schedule trigger for each of these, which would be the standard approach

One thing to try however is maybe you could exclude the months in the json in the schedule property see if it works (I dont think its going to work). Anyways, I think just having separate triggers for each of this would be enough, and its unnecessary to push for all-in-one schedule trigger approach (you dont lose anything from having separate triggers for these dates) So first thing you should ask yourself is what is the use case for having all the dates in one trigger while you can easily set up a separate one for each of these?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory#schedule-property

Also see this:

https://www.mutazag.com/blog/code/tutorial/ADF-custom-paramaters/#changing-trigger-settings